Using Roy's Lemma and Walras' Law to show that
I need some hint in here:
I am trying to show that an individual that has preferences that satisfy the usual assumptions: that is, use the assumptions, this is satisfied:
$$
x_{l}(p, 1)=\frac{\frac{\partial v(p, 1)}{\partial p_{l}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{L} p_{k} \frac{\partial v(p, 1)}{\partial p_{k}}} \quad \forall l=1, \ldots, L
$$
I have been thinking to use Roy's identity, but I am missing something....

You are right, in this case, we use Roy's Identity:
$$
x_{l}(p, w)=-\frac{\frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial p_{l}}}{\frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial w}}
$$
Since we want to show this for $w=1$, we need to could rewrite it for this particular case as follows:
$$
x_{l}(p, 1)=\frac{\frac{\partial v(p, 1)}{\partial p_{l}}}{-\frac{\partial v(p, 1)}{\partial w}}
$$
To sum up, it is enough to show that:
$$
-\frac{\partial v(p, 1)}{\partial w}=\sum_{k=1}^{L} p_{k} \frac{\partial v(p, 1)}{\partial p_{k}}
$$
In order to do so, we use Walras' Law:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{L} p_{k} x_{k}(p, w) & =w \\
\sum_{k=1}^{L} p_{k}\left(-\frac{\frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial p_{k}}}{\frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial w}}\right) & =w \\
\frac{-1}{\frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial w}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{L} p_{k} \frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial p_{k}}\right) & =w \\
\sum_{k=1}^{L} p_{k} \frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial p_{k}} & =-w \frac{\partial v(p, w)}{\partial w}
\end{aligned}
$$
Setting $w=1$ we get exactly what we wanted to show.
